# Cannot remove package gramps

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, dpkg

I used dpkg and apt-get to install, purge, remove *gramps* package different versions. It all went to situation when I cannot remove it fully and install clean.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gramps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gramps' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded
$ sudo dpkg -r gramps
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove gramps which isn't installed
$ locate gramps
See: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5da63c802469fa8cb20b
$ sudo apt-get install gramps
...
Unpacking gramps (from .../gramps_3.4.0-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gramps_3.4.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mime/packages/gramps.xml', which is also in package python-gramps 4.1.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your package index with `apt-get update`?

Looks like it's failing when it's `trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mime/packages/gramps.xml', which is also in package python-gramps 4.1.1`

You could try backing up the `/usr/share/mime/packages/gramps.xml` file in case you want to keep it, or just delete it, and then see if it will install?

I would have tried to purge the package, but since it's already removed that would be troublesome. And removing "python-gramps" might help if this fails, but if it were conflicting there should be a warning of such when you tried to isntall "gramps'.

Comment: `apt-get update` or removing `gramps.xml` doesn't change anything. `apt-get purge python-gramps` seemed to work, now I can install gramps again.